# How are the religious minorities spread over Syria?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, demographics, eastern-catholicism, middle-east

When hearing about the civil war in Syria often religious (and ethnic) minorities are mentioned. There are for example different kinds of muslims, Yazidis, different kinds of Eastern Orthodox Christians, different kinds of Eastern Catholic Christians.

My question is: How are these minorities spread over the country? I am not interested in statements like "Christians live in the North", but "There are whole provinces with nearly only Orthodox Christians with some scattered Eastern Catholic villages." or "The minorities live unseperated. In each village you will find one of each minority."

My focus is on Christians and esp. on how Eastern Rite Catholics are distributed among the Orthodox. Mentioning other minorities is good too.

I am interested in answers for before todays mobility (maybe 100 years ago) and for now (or before the war).